# Injecting Function with Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I am trying to inject this function to webpage with Puppeteer to get the event listeners of the website.

My code is:

```
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('*'))
  .reduce(function(pre, dom){
    var evtObj = getEventListeners(dom)
    Object.keys(evtObj).forEach(function (evt) {
      if (typeof pre[evt] === 'undefined') {
        pre[evt] = 0
      }
      pre[evt] += evtObj[evt].length
    })
    return pre
  }, {})
```

I have tried to run code below.

```
'use strict';

const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('https://google.com')
    
    
    var FunctionToInject = function(input){
        Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('*'))
        .reduce(function(pre, dom){
          var evtObj = getEventListeners(dom)
          Object.keys(evtObj).forEach(function (evt) {
            if (typeof pre[evt] === 'undefined') {
              pre[evt] = 0
            }
            pre[evt] += evtObj[evt].length
          })
          return pre
        }, {})
      

    }
    
    await page.exposeFunction('functionToInject', functionToInject);

    
    var data = await page.evaluate(async function(){
        return  await FunctionToInject();
    });
    
    console.log(data);
    

    await browser.close();
})();
```

I am getting **UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Evaluation failed: ReferenceError: document is not defined** error.
How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: This might be an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What goal is all of this supposed to achieve? Thanks.

Comment: One thing I notice is that there is a casing difference in how you name your function. There's both `FunctionToInject` and `functionToInject`. This shouldn't be generating an error about `document` not being defined, though.